# Does SageMath provide interactive tutorials?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sage

The second paragraph on [the SageMath tutorial tour page](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour.html) says

> If you are viewing the tutorial in the Sage notebook,
>   press shift-enter to evaluate any input cell.

Does that mean SageMath provides an interactive tutorial
set in the form of Jupyter notebooks? If I click on the
`Sage Tutorial` option in the sage notebook help menu, a
new html window opens with an offline copy of the tutorial
on the official site.

Does SageMath provide interactive tutorials in the form
of Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

So far, making the tutorials active only works in the legacy SageNB
notebook. Start it by running

```
sage -n sagenb
```

in a terminal, then access the documentation or tutorials from its menus,
and make them active.

Making this work for the Jupyter notebook too is tracked at:

- [Sage trac ticket #24593: Upgrade from Thebe to ThebeLab
  for live documentation support](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/24593)